# How to change width when browser width is changed...?

Tags: html

I recently made new HTML document in my computer. When I share it with other comp. which has small size monitor then everything is messed!!!

I just wanted to know if I can make a code which changes the width of the items in webpage according to device width...
Then afterwards I thought to use % in width instead of pixels (px). It worked but not how I wanted it . So I still need help...

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're looking for is media queries. Using media queries you can style your page using CSS based on the page max/min width.

Take a look at this for further info.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries

Here is an example when a screen has a max-width of 900px and when that is applied the following CSS will be applied. Anything outside of that range will have the above CSS applied

```
.example {
  font-size: 7rem;
  width: 75%;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 900px){

.example {
  font-size: 3.5rem;
  width: 50%;
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

A website designed to change its contents according to how big (or small) the monitor or screen is designed with Responsive Design principles in mind.

Responsive designs can be achieved with CSS media queries. Check out the MDN documentation on Responsive Design [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Responsive_Design).

Comment: Ok I will try it... Thanks